# write a Textview declared in MainActivity

Tags: android

i have declared a `TextView` in `MainActivity`, and i want to update it (write something else or update a value) in another class. for example in `Main Activity` I have

```
value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value_view);
```

How can I access this `TextView` in another class and update the value ?

Comment: Use an `interface` if logic calls for it. Or look into this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996479/how-to-update-a-textview-of-an-activity-from-another-class

Comment: Did you try passing the context reference as in this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996479/how-to-update-a-textview-of-an-activity-from-another-class?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create `TextView` object dynamically and give reference of previously created `TextView` to it.

```
TextView txt;
txt=(TextView)FindViewById(R.id.text_view);
txt.setText("New Content");
```

Comment: You can accept this answer if its helped you. Thanks.