# Java return input text value on click event

Tags: java

How can I get the value of an input field when I click a button?

For example I need the value of `textName` input from the `PersonalInfo` class to be used in another class called `GenerateRDF`

This is my code:

```
public class PersonalInfo extends JPanel {
    private void initialize() {
        ....
        JTextPane textName = new JTextPane();
        textName.setBounds(95, 36, 302, 20);
        panel.add(textName);

        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // send the value of `textName` to GenerateRDF
               GenerateRDF generator = new GenerateRDF();
               generator.setRDF();
            }
        }); 
   }
}

public class GenerateRDF {
      public void setRDF() {
        String personURI    = "http://localhost/amitkumar";
        String fullName = textName;

        // print here the value received from the `PersonalInfo` class
        System.out.println(fullName);
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

        Resource node = model.createResource(personURI)
                 .addProperty(VCARD.FN, fullName);
        model.write(System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this similar example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996479/how-to-update-a-textview-of-an-activity-from-another-class

Comment: Do you want to create a `GenerateRDF ` object when the button is pressed and send it the text of the `textName` field ?

Comment: @Titus , yes, exactly! I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public class PersonalInfo extends JPanel {
private void initialize() {
    ....
    JTextPane textName = new JTextPane();
    textName.setBounds(95, 36, 302, 20);
    panel.add(textName);

    JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // send the value of `textName` to GenerateRDF
           GenerateRDF generator = new GenerateRDF();
           generator.setRDF(textName.getText());
        }
    }); 
  }
}

public class GenerateRDF {
  public void setRDF(String fullName) {
    String personURI    = "http://localhost/amitkumar";

    // print here the value received from the `PersonalInfo` class
    System.out.println(fullName);
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

    Resource node = model.createResource(personURI)
             .addProperty(VCARD.FN, fullName);
    model.write(System.out);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `getText()` method in your buttons actionListener to store the input in a variable when it is clicked. Then pass this variable to your `GenerateRDF` class

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the value of an input field when I click a button?

There exists a method called **[getText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#getText())** which enables you to retrieve the text of your `textName` variable.

**Example:**

```
JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // send the value of `textName` to GenerateRDF
       String getName = textName.getText(); // retrieve the value 
       // do something with it
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[JtextPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) has a method you have to call... the [getText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#getText()) method

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // send the value of `textName` to GenerateRDF
        String input =  texName.getText();
  }
```