# How to find a ListView from a non-activity class with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my `MainActivity`, if I import:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

I can simply find my `ListView` and set `onItemClickListener` like this:

```
list_view.onItemClickListener
```

But how can I do the same thing in non-activity class?

**Edit:**

```
fun setListViewElements() {
    list_view.adapter = arrayAdapter
    list_view.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {}
}
```

Comment: how do tyou show your listview on screen in non-activity class?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Simply by using `list_view` without anything else. And just using that import.

Comment: Please, show full code. And where you want to call this list_view

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko This is my full code. I just use that import and it simply find my `ListView` without using `findViewById` or anything else.

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki What do you mean through "achieved with interfaces"?

Comment: okk.... sir what u want to do with listview in non-activity class u want to update it or etc..........

Comment: pass the main root view into non-activity class using constructor

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki First I just want to simply find it and then to update or anything else.

Comment: You can refer to the [documentation about synthetic properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) to find out how they work.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996479/how-to-update-a-textview-of-an-activity-from-another-class

Comment: @MarkusPenguin Thanks but do you know how to solve my case?

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki Is the same as kelalaka's answer.

Comment: @Ioana P. We can't understand your problem. Just show full code of your non-activity class and describe where are you want to call this list_view

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky Please see my updated question. I want to simply use: `list_view` as I do in my activity, ok?

Comment: Ok, I understand exactly place, but i have to see your non-activity class. What is it? EpoxyModel or View or something else?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky It's a simple plain kotlin class that contains a simple function, that in my updated answer.

Comment: If it's just simple class - you can't find your list_view event with findViewById. And I don't understand the reason of placing this function inside such class

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky It's a helper class, in which I define that function that will be called from within 4-5 activity classes. I know I can use `findViewById` but my question was in the first place, how I can achieve the same thing without using it. In my MainActivity I'm not using `findViewById` at all, just simply use `list_view` and that's it.

Comment: I said you can't use even findViewById. If it's just helper, which you call from different activities - it can't find any view. Could you show the constructor of this helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access views without `findViewById` by using the `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin and the `LayoutContainer` interface.

In your `build.gradle` file make sure that you apply the plugin and set the experimental flag:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

The class from which you want to access the `list_view` needs to implement the `LayoutContainer` interface. Implementing that interface means that you need to provide a container view in which your `ListView` can be found.

Now let's assume we have a simple layout that we use for the `MainActivity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In our `MainActivity` we use this file with `setContentView`.

Now you can write a class that is not an activity but is able to use a view (the `TextView` in this example) without using `findViewById`:

```
package com.example.playground

import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.extensions.LayoutContainer
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class Demo(override val containerView: View?) : LayoutContainer {

    fun setTextViewText(text: String) {
        text_view.text = text
    }

}
```

The class implements `LayoutContainer` (this is only possible if you first enable the experimental features) and therefore needs to provide the `containerView` property which it gets via the constructor.

Now to use this class e.g. from an activity you will need to instantiate it and give it the view in which `text_view` exists (the `LinearLayout` with the id `container` in my case):

```
val demo = Demo(container)
demo.setTextViewText("Magic!")
```

You will not be able to use `kotlinx.android.synthetic`-magic without providing a container. Because essentially what happens in the background is that if you access `list_view` the extension does a `findViewById`.

Online you can find additional information from [Kotlin about the Android plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) and about [how to use the Android extensions](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/).

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996479/how-to-update-a-textview-of-an-activity-from-another-class);

You have to pass the Context reference via constructor.

```
public class ClassB {
   Context context;
   public ClassB(Context context){
     this.context=context;
   }

   public void Update(){
        TextView txtView = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.text);
        txtView.setText("Hello");
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use `findViewById`, I just want to simply find my `ListView` as I do in the `MainActivity`. Is it possible?

Comment: are you using listviewActivity that extend the activity?

Comment: No, I'm simply using a single activity.

Comment: Can you write how you find? @B.M's solution is another one.

Comment: This is the problem, I don't find, I just use that import and simply use: `list_view` anywhere in my activity.

Comment: are you using <layout> in your xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass The `listView` as `constuctor` argument of your class like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

        ClassExample classExample = new ClassExample(listView);

    }
```

And :

```
class ClassExample {

        ListView listView;
        public ClassExample(ListView listView){
            this.listView = listView;
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps